# Adding 410 to page in .htaccess in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo

I want to ask is it correct the way that I add 410 to page in .htaccess in Wordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule http://exapmle.com/%D1%8BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8/ [G=410,L]
RewriteRule http://example.com/%D0%%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8/ [G=410,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your intent behind using `RewriteRule http://exapmle.com/%D1%8BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8/ [G=410,L]` ?

Comment: I want to set status 410 on that page
http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E410.html

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't want the `http://example.com` part in the pattern, that's not part of the URI that's used for the pattern to match against
2. You don't need the `=410` in the flags
3. The URI is already decoded by the time mod_rewrite rules get applied, so you don't want (I'm assuming) the URL encoded string.

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^ыBуги/ - [G,L]
RewriteRule ^ÐÑÐ°ÐºÑÐ¸/ - [G,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show `"Gone"` error for those 2 URLs (mentioned in your code) then put this code right on top of .htaccess after `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteRule ^\xD1\x8BB\xD1\x83\xD0\xB3\xD0\xB8/?$ - [G,L]

RewriteRule ^\xD0\xD1\x82\xD0\xB0\xD0\xBA\xD1\x82\xD0\xB8/?$ - [G,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%B3%D0%B8/ - [G,L]
RewriteRule ^/%D0%B7%D0%0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8/ - [G,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPdpress
```

or to put these two lines of URLs at the top ot the .htaccess file, outside of:

```
# BEGIN  WordPress
```